# "to ask details" vs "to ask for details"

Tags: prepositions, difference

[cambridge.org](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/ask-and-ask-for):
**(1)** *I called them to ask **for** more details*. — correct
**(2)** *I called them to ask more details*. — incorrect
Is (2) really incorrect?

Is "*to ask details*" (without "*for*") always incorrect?
If not, in what cases "*to ask details*" is incorrect and in what is correct?

For example (my own examples):
**(3)** *You need to ask him **for** some details about the upcoming meeting*.
**(4)** *You need to ask him some details about the upcoming meeting*.
Which of (3) and (4) is correct and which is not?

Answer (score 2):

You must ask **for** details.

Perhaps you're confused because you've heard the expression "ask questions". But questions are the thing you ask - you *ask* questions, and you *receive* replies. The details are your replies.

Comment: Proceeding from the internet: "for" is optional in "_to ask (someone) (for) an advice / an opinion / a permission / a favour / forgiveness / the time_". --- As far as I understand, there is no rule when "for" is optional and when "for" is obligatory. That is, an English leaner has to ask about every individual collocation with "ask" to understand if he necessarily needs to use "for" in it or not. Do you agree? Thanks.

Comment: @Loviii "ask your opinion", "ask your name" and some others are idiomatic. "Ask details" not so much.